# Does the Poco C++ Library Support positional command line arguments?

Tags: c++, command-line-arguments, poco-libraries

I can see no way to support positional command line arguments with [Poco's](http://pocoproject.org/) `Poco::Util::Application` class and related `Poco::Util::OptionProcessor`. Positional arguments are unnamed arguments on the command line, coming at the end after all other options, as such:

```
someprogram -b --what=121 filename.bin
```

In that example, filename.bin is a positional argument, it has no name, but is the first positional argument after all named arguments. Boost's program_options supports this, and I find it hard to believe Poco does not, but I can't discover how to support it given the source and documentation.

Does Poco support this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not familiar with Poco, but looking at the documentation, I suspect that the intended usage is to repeatedly call `Poco::Util::OptionProcessor::process()` on successive elements of `argv` until it returns `false`, and that would then signify the start of positional arguments and let you handle them however you wish.

Comment: Looks like you're right, except I don't need to re-call process(). When the main method is invoked the only arguments left are positional.